# Using expression-filter in undertow is not working

Tags: wildfly-10, undertow, mod-jk

I'm using Wildfly 10 and I'm trying to add an expression filter in the undertow configuration to validate the secret value from mod_jk. It is however always returning error code 403.

Below is my configuration in standalone-full.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:7.0" ...>
...
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
    <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        ...
        <!-- add the following with your AJP port (8009) -->
        <filter-ref name="secret-checker" predicate="equals(%p, 8009)"/>
    </host>
</server>
...
<filters>
    <!-- add the following with your credential (YOUR_AJP_SECRET) -->
    <expression-filter name="secret-checker" expression="not equals(%{r,secret}, 'verysecure') -> response-code(403)"/>
</filters>
```

Below is the configuration in workers.properties for mod_jk.

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=127.0.0.1
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.secret=verysecure
```

I'm trying to mitigate the ghostcat vulnerability detailed on this link.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4851251

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

place "**and equals(%{PROTOCOL}, 'AJP')"** after the port.

predicate="equals(%p, 8009) and equals(%{PROTOCOL}, 'AJP')"
but I am getting a 404 and not the expected 403 :(

Comment: You confused `%{PROTOCOL}` (which has on of these values: [Protocols](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/Protocols.java), with `%{TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL}` which has value `ajp` for AJP protocol. It's understandable as  knowing this requires one to read Undertow's source code.